# Access Superclass Fields from Angular 5 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, inheritance, angular5

I have a superclass which contains common functionality for components.

```
export class AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: User;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<User>('url').subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
}
```

I have a subclass which implements this superclass.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent extends AbstractComponent {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
}
```

In the headers template I am trying to access the user

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span *ngIf="user">Welcome {{user.username}}!</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

But the user field is not being resolved. How can I access a superclass's fields from a subclass?

Comment: Are you sure the user is fetch correctly? I use the exact same inheritance and it's working well for me.

Comment: Try putting it in your subclass, HeaderComponent, and see if it works first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error because the `user` object is not available at load.

Either initalise it or use the safe navigation operator (`?.`) inside your template

*initalise:*

```
public user: User = new User();
```

*safe navigation:*

```
<span>Welcome {{user?.username}}!</span>
```

Comment: The access to `user` is guarded inside an `ngIf` -- the statement `user.username` will never be evaluated with an undefined `user` because the `span` containing it won't be in the DOM.

Comment: @Coderer You are absolutely right. Updated my answer to reflect your comment. I have no idea why this worked for him :) and actually the answer below mine is better, by using an async pipe

Comment: I think your updated answer is worse, in a way.  The page will show `Welcome` with no name, until the user is loaded from the backend.  I would advise *declaring* `user` as potentially undefined, like `public user?: User`, then leaving the `ngIf` so that the `span` only appears after we know the username.  You might want to leave the safe navigation operator due to a longstanding issue where the AOT compiler doesn't type-narrow on `ngIf`.

Comment: @Coderer It was more in line with my points made above. It however depends, if you want to have a general 'Welcome!', when there is no user :). Use case dependent. What I proposed were two different solutions. A property initialisation, which might not make sense with a User.. perhaps a default anonymous one, or using the safe navigation operator. These are still not correct though. Best would be to use the async pipe, which is the answer below me

Answer (score 2):

This approach works but it is not a good practice. In such cases it would be better to use `async` pipe:

```
export class AbstractComponent {
  user$;
  constructor() {
    // your real http request should be here
    this.user$ = Observable.of({name: 'John Doe'});
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>Hello {{(user$ | async).name}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App extends AbstractComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i agree with this answer actually using async pipe in this case is more correct approach. qurboni40. +